# App to allow me to set which contacts dial out with Google Voice by default?

Tags: google-voice

I'd like to be able to set, at the contact level, which phone number is used to dial out.  For example, I'd like to be able to set it so calls to my boss use Google Voice by default where as calls to my family use my cell number.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Bryan may be right.  I've been searching for this functionality for sometime without success.  I've just about given up.  I hope someone here proves me wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still haven't tried Voice Choice, but I just downloaded this free app: [Voice Plus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/voice-plus/com.bbrother.googlevoicebyname)

This looks perfect.  From the description:

> Allows you to set rules for which number dialed will use your Google Voice number. Specify rules based on area code or by contacts (using contact groups). No more annoyance of having to press another button when dialing to choose where to call from!

Comment: It doesn't give you contact by contact level control like Voice Choice claims to but it gives you group control so I just added a contact group called Google Voice and make sure everyone I want to call with Google Voice is also in that group.

Comment: Seems like a recent update to the Google Voice app breaks Voice Plus (which switched to a [v2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bbrother.voiceplus&hl=en) version a while ago for some reason).  Not sure if the app is still maintained...

Answer (score 4):

I just found [Voice Choice](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.voiceplus) which claims to do what I want but I haven't tried it yet because its a big purchasing decision at $3.  I will have to discuss with the family and check with my financial advisor.  I'll report back if it actually does the job (or not).

Comment: Please do report back. BTW you might be able to help this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1075/15)... which is wondering the same thing about SMS.

Comment: There's a free version of it as well. I don't know what the difference is between free/paid.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Voice app it self only lets you choose three things: all calls with regular number, all calls with GV number, or you can choose at a call-by-call basis.  I do the call-by-call basis to get sort of what you want.  I don't think there is any way to automatically have it choose one way or another per contact level.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bryan, but that's not really an answer to my question.  I'm well acquainted with what the native Google Voice app is capable off.  I'm looking for any apps, hacks or mods that will build on this functionality and give me more control.  

I'm pretty new to the community so you can tell me if I'm off base on this but your response should probably be a comment not an answer.

Comment: The problem is that I'm pretty certain there are no apps to do what you're asking.  The biggest problem with Google Voice is there is no public API for developers to build applications against.  There is a crummy non-official API, but it returns full HTML responses, not JSON data or similar for developers to use. I've been wanting a similar thing myself, but currently it just isn't possible/available.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't address the real request, the widget available with the latest version of Google Voice makes it easier to switch modes as you can step through 4 modes (do not use for calls/International calls only/ask for every call/use for all calls) from your home screen.

The widget is fast, so I think once you learn the sequence, you'd be able to rapidly select the mode you want for a call before opening the phone app.    I only wish you could select which of the 4 icons in the widget you want displayed so it could use less than 3x1 spots on the home screen.

Comment: Thanks TomG.  Yes, the new widget does make it easier but call me picky, I don't want "easier" I want it to work the way I want it to work ;)  Voice Choice looks promising but still haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I agree; just offering the closest option we seem to have at the moment...

Answer (score -3):

You can do this with [voice plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bbrother.googlevoicebyname)