# How can I send SMS messages from my Google Voice number without using the Voice app?

Tags: sms, handcent-sms, google-voice

I would like to send text messages via Google Voice, as it is the number I give out for voice calls. However, I find sending SMS through the Voice app to be a bit cumbersome. The new widgets improve this somewhat, but it is still awkward.

I would prefer something with an interface more like Handcent or ChompSMS.

Are there any other apps that support sending SMS via Google Voice?

Comment: There is a similar question regarding using Google Voice # for some contacts and cell phone # for others. The OP is looking into this 
[answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245/app-to-allow-me-to-set-which-contacts-dial-out-with-google-voice-by-default/1085#1085) which involves getting the [Voice Choice](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.voiceplus) app. It's not clear if the app works for SMS though.

Comment: As near as I can tell, Voice Choice doesn't do SMS.

Comment: Voice Choice 2.0 does SMS as well.  It works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the cleanest solution, but it's an option:

If you set up your google voice number so SMS messages are forwarded to your phone, every time somebody texts you, you will receive that text from a 406 area code phone number.  If you send  a message back to that number, it will reach your that person, and appear to them as if it came from your google voice number.  So you can save the 406 number for each contact as a secondary phone number, and set it as the default number to use for SMS.

(if you think the Google Voice app is cumbersome, you should try doing it from an iPhone ;) )

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something a little cleaner, but if that's the only way, I may settle on that.

Comment: If the sending phone number that the recipient sees is your top priority, then I think this is a pretty decent way. But if you also want to manage your text-message costs, then this isn't such a good way since each message sent or received will still count toward the limits set by your service provider; messages that go directly through GV get applied to your data plan instead.

Comment: You can get google voice to forwrd your texts as emails; then you just reply to them using the email client on the phone and that goes back to the originator as SMS.